# Replace words in a string using regular expressions C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
string sentence = "My current address is #6789, Baker Avenue (CB)".
```

I would like to replace `#6789, Baker Avenue (` with `#574, Tomson Street (`.

Regular expression would be `^#.*($`

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: `var result = sentence.Replace("#6789, Baker Avenue (","#574, Tomson Street (");` sorted

Comment: is `string sentence` the only example of what needs to be replaced? or do you have more of those sentences that share a certain pattern?

Comment: All the issues are too well-known, see the linked threads that answer and  *teach* you how to solve such problems in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string address = "My current address is #6789, Baker Avenue (CB)";
        Regex regex = new Regex("#.+\\(");
        address = regex.Replace(address, "#574, Tomson Street (");
        Console.WriteLine(address);
    }
}
```

You need to escape the opening bracket. Also in c# \ character must be escaped, so we need the combination \\(
I have removed ^ and $ form your proposal. That characters anchor the pattern to the beginning and end of the phrase. And this is not the case.

Comment: Kinda unrelated, do you know how to quickly test .net regexp online? http://regexstorm.net/tester seems to never work for me. Giving issues with this pattern too.

Comment: I just have tested on it. Just put `#.*\(` as pattern and `My current address is #6789, Baker Avenue (CB)` as input

Comment: @Erndob try this one: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string sentence = "My current address is #6789, Baker Avenue (CB)";

var result = Regex.Replace(sentence, @"#\d+,[^(]+", "#574, Tomson Street ");
```

The pattern is `#\d+,[^(]+`.

It's a hash `#`, followeg by at least one digit `\d+`, comma, and at least one character which isn't opening bracket: `[^(]+`